# Importance / usefulness of learning Latin word roots

Tags: etymology

Since taking English exams known to be difficult to native speakers, like the GRE, I have become more aware of Latin word roots contained in various dictionaries. (I scored a full 6 out of 6 on the writing section without any preparation, just so that you know.)
However, if one looks at the dictionary word roots themselves, they are in many cases, not very informative for two reasons:

1. they are already similar to the destination word because they cannot be partitioned into smaller root syllables and
2. the word roots' meanings have changed so significantly through time that they don't do much to help understand the word's main definition

What I am finding helpful is to know very common root words that are directly related to some easily accessible, everyday concept, to list some that comes to my mind (some may not be very accurately defined)

1. *capere* (to catch, grasp), *ducere* (to lead), *ducare* (to bring out), *fligere* (to hit), *lingere* (tongue, to speak), *linquere* (to relinquish or push away), *solere* (to be accustomed to), *manere* (to do something with your hands), *valere* (valid, valuable), *parare* (to push away; as in compatible, parry etc), *equus* (on horseback, between equals like equity holders), *parvus* (small, partial), *magnus* (magnanimous, magnificent, large, big etc)

What I've also found is that to know these "root of root" words it is advisable to either

1. Read the entire dictionary and collect those words from scratch
2. Read a Latin textbook like "Wheelock's Latin".

My question is, then, is the advice "not to learn Latin if you are simply seeking the etymology of words", sound advice?

Comment: _Equus_ means _a horse_ and is not linked to _equal_, which comes from the Latin _aequalis_. If you happen to know some Latin it can help with knowing the meanings of words, but I wouldn't recommend studying Latin for the sole purpose of learning English.

Comment: As you see, this can lead to a lot of false appropriation, like the propensity for people to think the plural of octopus is octopii, where it's actually just octopuses. If you were to insist on a classical plural, it would be octopodes, from the Greek, not the Latin.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noted, learning etymology is of limited use. The development of sense from Latin to English is often too divergent to be of any real use.  Consider "essay".  Could you guess the meaning from its Latin roots *ex-*(out) and *agere* (to set in motion, drive)?

Now, depending on how you learn, you might find the etymology an interesting motivator.  If you can note that all the "-ceive" words share a common element, even if their meanings are divergent, that might be the sort of interesting tidbit that keeps your brain happy while you get it to learn the actual meaning of words. Etymology can be the dressing that helps you eat all your vegetables.

Learning some Latin is also interesting of itself.  It can be enjoyable to read the words of people like Julius Caesar.  Not *useful*, but *fun*.  Of course to learn Latin you'll need a Latin textbook or teacher.

Please note that while a lot of English vocabulary is taken from Latin (either directly or via Old French, and occasionally through other routes) The core language is Germanic, and derives from Anglo-Saxon.

Among your list the connection between equus (horse) and equal is a false etymology. Equal comes directly from Latin *aequalis/aequus* (which has no known PIE root). Partial is from *partus* ="brought forth, (and hence) a share". It is distinct from *parvus*.

Comment: The Latin exagium meant "drive out", and by extension "drive out the truth, or test something by weighing it".  So the Old French *essai* mean a test or trial (a meaning preserved in English "assay", or test the purity of gold).  When Michel de Montaigne developed the "short personal written inquiry into some matter", he called it an "essai", as it was a test of his ideas.  This was borrowed into English, (with inevitable spelling changes) as "essay". The "personal test" aspect of essays was lost, and they became just a short written discussion of a single topic.

Comment: I was forced to learn Latin from age 11 to 16, and was told that it would help me learn languages other than English, (i.e. 'Romance' languages) and I can honestly say that turned out to be true for French, Spanish and Italian, and lately, Catalan. _Latin is a language as dead as dead can be; it killed the ancient Romans, and now it's killing me!_